# Display new field when choose specific value (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14698783/project/register/form.htm

The city input is hidden by default.
I want to display it when the visitor choose USA or Canada only.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  As it stands, you haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: I tried some JS code and I used change() functions with jQuery library, without any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I'm using jQuery. First, I set up and event handler for the country dropdown using the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method - this will be raised when the value is changed (not surprisingly). Then test if the value selected is in a set of accepted values (for this, I'm using the ['in' operator](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/testing_for_a_v)). Since `this` is an input element, I can just reference element.value without wrapping it in jQuery. Finally, use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), passing in the boolean value to indicate if the select should be shown or hidden.

```
var valuesToShowFor = [0, 1]; // USA + Canada

$("#title").change(function() {
    var shouldShowCity = (this.value in valuesToShowFor);
    $("#city").toggle(shouldShowCity);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/xULyc/

For this, I recommend having IDs on your elements. It makes it much easier and neater to do the jQuery selects - otherwise you'd need something like `$("input[name='title']")` to reference the element.

Comment: thank you so much. the code work, i added an id to each element.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some clues for you:

1. Catch onchange with jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
2. Get the selected option value with jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
3. If the selection option value is one of those you need, use jQuery [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show the other input box (and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide it)

Comment: that was exactly whet I did. Thank you